# Switch element not centre aligning horizontally within allocated space

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-percent-library

After creating a `PercentRelativeLayout`, I noticed that the `SwitchCompat` control does not align to the center horizontally despite settings properties. What can be done in order to resolve this issue? I tried using `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`, but this doesn't seem to work.

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        app:layout_widthPercent="40%"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_image1" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/switch_map_emiratesairline_emiratesgreenwichpeninsula"
        app:layout_widthPercent="20%"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageView1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_widthPercent="40%"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_image2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/switch_tgl"/>
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might look like a bug, but actually it doesn't relate to `SwitchCompat` (as issue is reproduced for `Switch` as well.
But it also doesn't relate to `PercentRelativeLayout`. And even doesn't relate to `RelativeLayout`.
It relates to Switch with width different from `wrap_content` (as far as I can see).

Simple example:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Neither `gravity` nor `layout_gravity` has effect on switch's position - it is aligned to the right.
One can replace `FrameLayout` with `LinearLayout` and result will be the same.
To understand why this happens one should try to find answer in Switch/SwitchCompat source code (sorry, I haven't tried to do so...)

So, to resolve your issue the only thing I could come up with is a hack: wrap `SwitchCompat` with some layout. And use `wrap_content` as `SwitchCompat` width.

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        app:layout_widthPercent="40%"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/avatar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/switch_tgl"
        app:layout_widthPercent="20%"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView1">
        <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_widthPercent="40%"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/avatar"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/switch_tgl"/>
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I would even call it a bug since it makes it necessary to add an otherwise unneeded layout.

Comment: It's also still happening in AndroidX to this date